# Change an element in a list using scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I want to change element in a list, >(change '(1 2 2 4) 2 5) so that the remaining elements in
the list will be (1 5 4).

```
(define change
    (lambda (mylist num val)
        (cond ((null? mylist) '())
            (((equal? (car mylist) num) (cons val))     
                (change (cdr mylist) num val))
            (else 
                (cons (car mylist) 
                (change (cdr mylist) num val))))))
```

Comment: @Sylwester sorry .. you're right it's (1 5 5 4) rather.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I changed the excessive and missing parens like I hinted in the comments and pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> and this is the result:

```
(define change
  (lambda (mylist num val)
    (cond ((null? mylist) '())
          ((equal? (car mylist) num) (cons val     
                                           (change (cdr mylist) num val)))
          (else 
           (cons (car mylist) 
                 (change (cdr mylist) num val))))))
```

Notice how `(change ...)` is the second argument to `cons` and it is placed right under on the same margin as `val`? Identation is very important for spotting errors so do press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> a lot! I would have moved the whole thing a little like this though:

```
(define change
  (lambda (mylist num val)
    (cond ((null? mylist) '())
          ((equal? (car mylist) num)
           (cons val
                 (change (cdr mylist) num val)))
          (else 
           (cons (car mylist) 
                 (change (cdr mylist) num val))))))
```

Still. Se how `(cons` is rigth under `(equal..` and not under the first paren while `(else` is? The identation tells you where `cond` clauses start and the structure of the code.

Looking at the code presented in your question the identation doesn't match the actual code since then `(else..)` would be in the `(change..` list. It was actually impossible for me to see what was wrong before I reidented it.